# mocha test post request with image fields raising error response 400

Tags: node.js, jasmine, mocha.js

I am trying to test the response for a **POST** request in mocha. The request body contains the fields name,phone number and and logo(image).
But I am getting 400 as the response.Attaching my snippet of test code here.

```
var sample_company =  {"name": "Test_company",
                       "phoneNumber": '+123456741538'
};
it('company  registartion', function(done){  
       request(app)
       .post('/companies')  
       .set({apikey: 'TestHashKey',headers: headers})  
       .type('form')  
       .send(sample_company)  
       .attach('log', "http://atomhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/TWNEL.png")  
       .expect(200)  
       .end(function(err,res) { 
         if (err) throw err;
         done();  
        });
});
```

Comment: Provide error description.

Comment: 2015-10-29T09:07:08.255Z - error: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 09:07:08 GMT uncaughtException: ENOENT, open 'http://atomhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/TWNEL.png'
2015-10-29T09:07:08.255Z - error: Error: ENOENT, open 'http://atomhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/TWNEL.png'
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Use it correctly: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/144. Attach can't take file from 'http://', It would take it from your local fs.

Comment: Ok. Is there any flaw in the syntax ? Actually I am running the test within the server. I cannot add the images manually, that's why i have given the file so. Is there any alternative methods to attach file ?